# Passing swift struct pointer to C function

Tags: ios, pointers, struct, swift

Let's say, I have Swift struct named Foo

```
struct Foo
{
     var a,b,c : Float
     var d : Double
     init()
     {
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        d = 0
     }
}
```

Swift sizeof(Foo) prints 24 bytes, 4 bytes for Float fields, 8 for Double and 4 bytes of padding on arm64.

So I consider, that there is no special Swift magic with structures alignment done, and we can freely pass pointers to it to internal C functions in order to use stuff like NEON and Metal, as long as built-in variables are unions, which currently can't be directly included into Swift

Somehow, when I try to get const void* to it (ConstUnsafePointer<()> in Swift) with

```
let a = Foo()
let b = &a
```

I get nasty compiler error on second expression

```
'Foo' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T1'
```

Did I miss something and this is done by design?

## UPDATED PART

Martn R, thanks for answer! Still, entire situation is not very clear for me. My aim was to create convenient Math stuff wrapper, so I wanted to implement @infix methods like multiplication and hide all internal native stuff behind C. In case of Matrices, for example, that means, that we need to pull ampersand right from a = &b*&c expressions, because I didn't get from your answer and Docs if there is a way to bypass this and get raw point from memory in the scope of @infix method implementation.

Like this:

```
@infix public func *(l: Mat4, r: Mat4) -> Mat4
{
    var m = Mat4()
    _internalMat4Multiply(&l, &r, &m)
}
```

_internalMat4Multiply is void(void*, void*, void*) C-method, doing all the computations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems: You cannot take the address of a *constant* (defined with `let`),
and you can pass the address of a variable only to function parameters.
Assuming that your C function is

```
void myFunc(const void *data);
```

then this would work:

```
var a = Foo()
myFunc(&a)
```

However, instead of making assumptions about identical alignment in C and Swift, you 
should perhaps better define the structure in your C API:

```
struct Foo {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    double d;
};

void myFunc(const struct Foo *data);
```

and use that from the Swift code:

```
var a = Foo(a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0)
myFunc(&a)
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, I would be pleased, if you could look at updated part and tell what you think

Comment: @ElijahIgny: Try declaring your function as `@infix public func *(var l: Mat4, var r: Mat4) -> Mat4`